# If i run several Azure Search Indexers in rapid succession, is there a way to access that queue of waiting indexers in the Azure SDK?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have several searches that my application uses and they are relatively big searches, millions of documents each, I am looking to simply display the queue of indexers waiting to run on a page in my application. This is so I can have a better insight into what will be finished and when since I know roughly how long each one should take.

I'm able to find the one currently in progress but not the ones that have yet to run in the SDK. I've done some digging around in the SDK but turned up nothing and I also don't see anything referring to it in the documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/indexer-operations

It doesn't seem like its an option but I'm not sure why it wouldn't be

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.search.models.indexerexecutioninfo?view=azure-dotnet

Doesn't seem to be anything here either about being scheduled to run

This is the Indexer class

```
public class Indexer : IResourceWithETag
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the Indexer class.
    public Indexer();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the Indexer class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   name:
    //     The name of the indexer.
    //
    //   dataSourceName:
    //     The name of the datasource from which this indexer reads data.
    //
    //   targetIndexName:
    //     The name of the index to which this indexer writes data.
    //
    //   description:
    //     The description of the indexer.
    //
    //   schedule:
    //     The schedule for this indexer.
    //
    //   parameters:
    //     Parameters for indexer execution.
    //
    //   fieldMappings:
    //     Defines mappings between fields in the data source and corresponding target fields
    //     in the index.
    //
    //   isDisabled:
    //     A value indicating whether the indexer is disabled. Default is false.
    //
    //   eTag:
    //     The ETag of the Indexer.
    public Indexer(string name, string dataSourceName, string targetIndexName, string description = null, IndexingSchedule schedule = null, IndexingParameters parameters = null, IList<FieldMapping> fieldMappings = null, bool? isDisabled = null, string eTag = null);

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the name of the indexer.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the description of the indexer.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the name of the datasource from which this indexer reads data.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "dataSourceName")]
    public string DataSourceName { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the name of the index to which this indexer writes data.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "targetIndexName")]
    public string TargetIndexName { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the schedule for this indexer.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "schedule")]
    public IndexingSchedule Schedule { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets parameters for indexer execution.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "parameters")]
    public IndexingParameters Parameters { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets defines mappings between fields in the data source and corresponding
    //     target fields in the index.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "fieldMappings")]
    public IList<FieldMapping> FieldMappings { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets a value indicating whether the indexer is disabled. Default is false.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "disabled")]
    public bool? IsDisabled { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the ETag of the Indexer.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@odata.etag")]
    public string ETag { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Validate the object.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException:
    //     Thrown if validation fails
    public virtual void Validate();
}
```

Since I only care about running several indexers at once at any point in time, not on schedule, the indexing schedule doesn't give me the information I need

```
//
// Summary:
//     Represents a schedule for indexer execution.
public class IndexingSchedule
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the IndexingSchedule class.
    public IndexingSchedule();
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the IndexingSchedule class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   interval:
    //     The interval of time between indexer executions.
    //
    //   startTime:
    //     The time when an indexer should start running.
    public IndexingSchedule(TimeSpan interval, DateTimeOffset? startTime = null);

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the interval of time between indexer executions.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "interval")]
    public TimeSpan Interval { get; set; }
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the time when an indexer should start running.
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "startTime")]
    public DateTimeOffset? StartTime { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Validate the object.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   T:Microsoft.Rest.ValidationException:
    //     Thrown if validation fails
    public virtual void Validate();
}
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Sorry, just updated it with the links i was looking at

Answer (score 0):

The SDK does not provide the ability to see which Indexers will run next when kicked off in rapid succession. If you'd like to request the ability to do this, please add this suggestion on [Azure Search UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that

Comment: @MattBruzik Do you mind also provide more information here on the scenario where you'd want to know which indexer is going to run next?